# libspotify on OS X 10.5 and missing symbol

Tags: macos, spotify

Is anyone successfully running stuff compiled with libspotify on Leopard? I have an Intel Mac with 10.5.8 and just can't seem to get it to work. I threw my libspotify 12.1.51 to /Library/Frameworks and compiled the "stub" example with

```
gcc -o stub main.c ../appkey.c -framework libspotify
```

It compiles and links OK, but when I run it

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ___bzero
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/libspotify.framework/libspotify
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: ___bzero
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/libspotify.framework/libspotify
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

So bzero() is a legacy function used to reset memory and it's implementation is apparently missing from my verion of libc. Is it there on some older/newer versions of OS X?

Comment: It works fine on 10.6+, so bzero is there on newer systems at least. I remember having trouble when we started compiling Spotify stuff on the 10.6 SDKs — there were a few things that weren't binary compatible with 10.5 or lower and it made supporting older versions of the OS a pain.